MUI-X TimePicker component's referenceDate prop
I have @mui/x-date-pickers-pro: ^6.10.0 installed. How should I set the referenceDate? I'm using moment as date-time library and have tried giving the referenceDate prop value moment(). This doesn't do anything.
If value is not set, I would like to have the time picker dialog open up at the current time, not 00:00. But referenceDate={moment()} doesn't affect this. With the prop, the picker still opens up at 00:00
